# I want to rewrite url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want rewrite my from : url https://www.domainname.in/news.php?slug=this-is-title-of-article to: https://www.domainname.in/this-is-title-of-article

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([\w-]+)$ /news.php?slug=$1 [END,QSA]
```

However to prevent conflicts with other parts of your web application I would suggest that you use the URL `https://example.com/news/this-is-title-of-article` instead of `https://example.com/this-is-title-of-article`. This allows for a more specific rule which will give you less headaches:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/news/?([\w-]+)$ /news.php?slug=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Comment: This does not really help. You will have to start taking care of your task yourself, we cannot carry you over the line. So: what does your http servers error log file say, any related entries? What happens if you place a definite syntax error in that file, do you receive an error, any change? If not: are you really sure that the interpretation of such dynamic configuration files is enabled _at all_ for that location? Where did you place the file? How did you create it?